# printf() and scanf() doesn't scan nor print all chars, C language

Tags: c

I'm trying to scan four chars from the user.
it exists the program after the third letter is scanned, prints the three chars and exists.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    char fc, sc, tc, frc;

    printf("Enter four lowercase letters");

    scanf("%c %c %c %c",&fc,&sc,&tc,&frc);

    printf("%c %c %c %c",fc,sc,tc,frc);
}
```

for example if the input will be "a b c d"
it stops after "c" and prints:

```
a b c
```

Comment: I don't reproduce the behavior you describe for the input you present.  However, the result would be different if the input had a leading space character or newline: " a b c d".  That would be because the first space would be read into `fc` as data.  You could avoid that by adding a leading space to the `scanf()` format: `" %c %c %c %c"`.  You might be less inclined to input that leading space if your prompt ended in a newline and / or a colon (`:`) or similar.

Comment: That output doesn't match your example. There's no newlines in the `printf` shown. Works here: https://godbolt.org/z/7z794PMaG Usually you'd want a space before the first `%c` as well to skip any leading whitespace that may be in the buffer from previous input, but there isn't any in this example so it shouldn't make a difference. Add delimiters around the characters in the `printf` so you can isolate each one, like `printf("'%c' '%c' '%c' '%c'", ... );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pressing return/enter after the prompt, or typing a space or other “white space” character, and `scanf` reads that for the first `%c`. Either enter the “a” immediately, without a return/enter or other key, or insert a space before the first `%c`. A space tells `scanf` to read and discard white-space characters.